# Could we change the title of this sub-stack, as well as the image which seems to hype a five-fold cross-validation strategy?

Tags: discussion, site-name, site-promotion, display-names, cross-validated

Validation is not inherently tied to repetition over folds. Considering the hundreds of "unanswered" questions [tagged](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-validation) with [cross-validation] (meaning no answer is either up-voted or accepted), I propose the following new design:

Name: Statistics

Symbol: A Cauchy pdf overlaid with Gaussian, showing fat tails of former.

Comment: Please see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/results-of-site-name-poll.  https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/what-should-our-site-be-called-what-should-our-domain-name-be might be helpful, too.  Given your previous attempts to raise this issue on Meta and the extreme downvoting they received (especially https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5996/919), this post comes across as quixotic.

Answer (score 10):

I take the name to mean that we do not just check one source (many members can answer), much as cross validation, as opposed to just checking on one out-of-sample set, checks many out-of-sample sets.

I would have voted for "Confidence Region" eleven years ago, but I like the name we have and see no reason to change.