# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Hi all, as you can see, the new design went live both here and on the parent site.

Congrats and thank you for your design input this week!

Please let me know if you see any CSS or styling issues. Do **start a new post** for bug reports, and tag it with "design" and "bug" so I can easily track them.

P.S. To make the new favicons show up in your browser, you can manually refresh if they're being cached. load the following URLs in your browser and hit control+F5.

http://sstatic.net/stats/img/favicon.ico
http://sstatic.net/statsmeta/img/favicon.ico

Comment: Looks cool. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Great job! Just one thing: can you please change the page titles (the title that appears in the browser titlebar) to "Cross Validated" or "Cross Validated - Stack Exchange". It is still showing up as "Statistical Analysis - Stack Exchange".

Comment: I was just going to say that! Sweet design anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Another thing I just noticed. The normal densities for the accepted answers have tails that are too short. The ones used for up and down votes look more normal. Can we make the green symbols for accepted answers more like these? The correct shape is given at [What should our logo and site design look like?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like/491#491)

Comment: I agree the shape is a bit off on the homepage. are they OK to you on the /question page?

Comment: @Jin. They are probably close enough on the question page. The up-vote symbol is even better. If you could just scale up the up-vote shape that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, nice work and thank you. It all looks very professional and grown up.

One minor detail I'm unsure about is the kerning in the logo -- "alidated" seems rather tight, while there's a bit much space after the V.

Otherwise I like it. Well done -- and congratulations to all who sail in her!

Comment: good catch, I'll tweak it.

Comment: It looks better now.

Answer (score 2):

Although I didn't participate to the extensive chat session, I must say that you've made a very neat job. Congrats!

Apparently, there's no probs with Safari 5.0.2 on a Mac OS 10.6.

Answer (score 1):

Looks very nice on my desktop and laptop. Looks terrible on my PDA though - the background 'squared paper' image comes out much darker and makes the text virtually unreadable. My PDA is running Windows Mobile 6 Classic and whatever cut-down version Intenet Explorer came with that (can't find a version number). The beta design looked fine. I can turn images off once i remember, but then I have to turn them back on afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

One other thing: I've just posted an answer with some external URIs and was a bit disconcerted to see them display in red. To me, red links look like broken links or links to empty pages as this is the convention on Wikipedia and other wikis. Is this just me?

Comment: I didn't interpret the links that way. But maybe that's just me. :-)

Comment: Maybe i spend too long on Wikipedia!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the new **top bar** which was launched recently:

The below thread on Meta Stack Overflow provides alternatives for its customization.

[Gallery of custom styles and/or scripts for the top-bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210041/gallery-of-custom-styles-and-or-scripts-for-the-top-bar)

Some suggestions merge features from new and old versions; others provide examples for color changing.

Comment: i just pushed a color change for the topbar on the main CV site. it has a hint of dark gray green to match the rest of the site design.

Answer (score 0):

The background image colors don't appear to match the CSS background colors on Windows:

[image]

Might [this](http://www.viget.com/inspire/the-mysterious-save-for-web-color-shift/) have something to do with it?

Comment: I'm looking into this. thanks.

Comment: I have put in a fix, it will be in the next deployment

Comment: It looks like this one has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the logo on stackexchange.com site lacks white bars:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Great job! One side comment however; i understand the desire to have tame colors, but it's very hard to see the difference in colors between the the links to the questions that have been visited already, and the links that have not been visited already (in the pages listing questions,i.e. for example on the main page). Can that be somehow accentuated ?

Comment: I'll make the visited links a different shade. I missed this initially, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Jin: its fixed: thanks.